# Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value Excel range cell input

Tags: sql, excel

This works fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Accounts (NOLOCK)
WHERE Accounts.created >= '27/12/2017'
  AND created < '27/12/2017'
```

But when I try to set these parameters from a cell in Excel:

```
FROM Accounts (NOLOCK)
WHERE Accounts.created >= '" & Range("b9")&"'
  AND created < '" & Range("b8")&"'
```

I get this error:

> Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I tried to format the cells but nothing. Any clues?

`Accounts.created` is of `datetime` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

use CDate to convert the value as date

```
CDate(Range("b9"))
```

Comment: I tried this     SELECT * FROM Accounts (NOLOCK)
WHERE Accounts.created >= 'CDate(Range("b8"))'
 AND 
created < 'CDate(Range("b9"))'   but not working..sorry Im newbie, same error

Comment: try like this - Accounts.created >=   ' & CDate(Range("b8")) & '

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string